# subtract values of same column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I´m trying to subtract the values of a weight column order by date desc, so I can get the difference between them ,example:

weight values :90-93-94-97

desired output: 0-3-1-3

90-90 | 93-90 |94-93| 97-94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Lite does not support running total or cumulative totals. But you can compute it round about way

Assume the following tables: `tb_user`, `tb_weight`:

```
|------------------|    |----------------------|
|   Id   | Name    |    |UserId| Date  | Weight|
|------------------|    |----------------------|
|   U1   | John    |    |  U1  | 1-Jan | 90    |
|   U2   | Jill    |    |  U2  | 2-Jan | 93    |
|------------------|    |  U1  | 3-Jan | 94    |
                        |  U2  | 4-Jan | 97    |
                        |----------------------|


    SELECT user.name, 
           current.date, 
           current.weight, 
           current.weight - (SELECT previous.weight -- select weight on the previous day available
                               FROM tb_weight previous
                              WHERE previous.date < current.date
                                AND previous.userId = user.id
                           ORDER BY previous.date DESC
                              LIMIT 1) -- select the top 1 record
    FROM tb_weight current
  INNER JOIN tb_user users ON (users.id = current.UserId)
      ORDER BY current.date DESC
```

Update on 22SEP2014: Added join with User table as requested

Comment: Is there a way of construct this query in order to get the result by user id? Now I have a table users and in my weight table I've add a field that references the user table .

Comment: I updated the sample code with join to user table. Check it out

Answer (score 1):

Here's a query that joins to rows to the previous row  (except for the first weight row, which subtracts itself)

```
select x.date, x.weight, x.weight - coalesce(y.weight, x.weight) delta
from (
  select w.date, w.weight, max(d.date) previous
  from weights w
  left join weights d on d.date < w.date
  group by w.date, w.weight) x
left join weights y on y.date = previous
order by x.date
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2bb13/4) using data:

```
2014-01-01 90
2014-01-02 93
2014-01-03 94
2014-01-04 94
2014-01-05 93
2014-01-06 97
```

and producing output of:

```
date        weight  delta
2014-01-01  90      0
2014-01-02  93      3
2014-01-03  94      1
2014-01-04  94      0
2014-01-05  93      -1
2014-01-06  97      4
```